# Random phase approximation for interacting electron gas

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, electrons, feynman-diagrams

I am studying some quantum field theory from "Altland, Simons - Condensed matter field theory": in particular the RPA approximation for the free energy of an interacting electron gas at finite temperature (page 216).
The general formula for a "n-loop Feynman diagram" is:

$$ F^{(n)}_{RPA} = - \frac{T}{2n} \sum_{q} \left( \frac{2T}{L^3}V(q) \sum_{p}G(p)G(p+q) \right)^n $$

($T$ is temperature, $L^3$ is the volume, $G$ is the non-interacting green function).
There are some details I can't figure out:

- I have troubles with those factors 2;
- it is said that the factor $1/n$ is due to the $1/n!$ of the perturbative expansion (ok!) and to another $(n-1)!$ due to different ways of arranging interaction lines in a ring diagram (what does this mean?).

Thanks for any help.

PS: I googled it but couldn't find anything helpful because I don't want to use self-energies (I want to expand the grand canonical partition function like $Z_n/Z_0 = (-1)^n/n! \left\langle S^n_{int} \right\rangle_0 $).

Comment: Altland is not intended to teach a green-handed at all although he claimed and pretended to be so.  You can resort to Bruus and Flensberg to learn Green's function methods.